# Predicate logic compare

Tags: discrete-mathematics, predicate-logic

### Heading ##I'm searching for references(text, videos, etc) on how to solve problems like this one.

Have just been working with how to rewriting expressions so they don't include $¬$ but, as you might understand I'm quite new to this and find it a bit challenging(not even sure what to search for that's why I'm here). I know that it should end up like "Both expressions are logically equivalent, meaning that a is prime." But I want to understand why that is.

### Problem:

Throughout this task, the basis for all elements is $\mathbb{N}' \{1,2,3…n\}$

For which '$a$' are the following precepts true:

$P(a)=∀b∀c |(b=1)∨(c=1)∨¬(a=bc)$
and $Q(a)=¬∃b∃c |(b>1)∧(c>1)∧(a=bc)$

Thankful for all tips and on how to solve something like this, or information about the topic in general.

Regards,
Petter

Comment: Arithmetic formulae are essentially never "logically" equivalent.  They might be equivalent *given particular axioms for arithmetic.*

So to get an answer, you'll need to include more information on the formal system that you're working with.  To do that, it's probably best to tell us what textbook you've been studying.

Comment: First step : apply the equivalence between $\lnot \exists$ and $\forall \lnot$ to the right-hand formula to get : $\forall b \forall c \lnot [(b > 1) \land (c > 1) \land (a=bc)]$.

Comment: Second step : apply De Morgan's laws to move inside the negation sign, to get : $∀b∀c[¬(b>1) \lor ¬(c>1) \lor ¬(a=bc)]$.

Comment: Up to now, we have used only logical equivalences.

Comment: The issus is with e.g $\lnot (b > 1)$. Only if we assume that $\mathbb N$ is defined starting from $1$ (instead of starting from $0$) we have that from it we may conclude that $(b=1)$.

Comment: Thanks, @MauroALLEGRANZA that help me to understand it a bit more clearly. Was able to solve a few following tasks now.

Comment: Hi, @Dabbler its something that my professor has put together by himself and a team of other professors on my campus. So it is just an internal pdf. Its a bachelor degree in Information security

Comment: As per first comemnt, in order to prove it you need arithmetical axioms, like e.g. $\lnot \exists x (1= x+1)$ and the def : $n > m \leftrightarrow \exists x (n=m+x)$.